# What Language Generation is c#?

Tags: c#

What Language Generation is c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3rd.

reference:
- [Third-generation programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-generation_programming_language)

Comment: I would argue a mix of 3 and 4. LINQ is quite a specific tool .

Answer (score 3):

I don't think ‘generation’ is a relevant term any more. The only *GL categorisation that was really recognisably well-defined was 4GL, and thankfully the 4GLs have largely died off.

That leaves almost everything in the 3GL box, from systems languages to scripting languages to functional programming. A category that encompasses that kind of diversity is of little practical use.

Comment: I agree.  These days, if on the rare occasion I hear someone talking about 3GL, 4GL etc I assume them to be non-programmers.  There are far more meaningful categories such as those you mention.

Answer (score 1):

3rd. Think of them as 'closeness to Natural English'

- 1 = Machine Language (Binary etc)
- 2 = ASM
- 3 = C / C++ / C# / Java etc - Most modern languages fall in here somewhere.
- 4 = SQL like syntax (EXTRACT ALL NAMES FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE....)

Comment: Then AppleTalk would be like 803702. Fail.

Comment: wouldn't that make COBOL a 4th generation language? *shudders*

Comment: Oh, please fail me on that previous comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript-- AppleScript, not AppleTalk.

Comment: A higher generation doesn't mean it has to be any good ;)

Comment: Where would C# IL be classified? Because it's lower level than C#, but it's still machine independent so it isn't really 2nd gen either